# Jquery Ajax PHP Mysql Autocomplete not Functioning

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

Can someone please take a look at [this link](http://iomhumanitarian.atwebpages.com/pointer.php) and let me know why the auto complete text box is not functioning?

What I have is a Table called `Brangays` in a **MySQL** datadabase "`157400X_XXXXXX` which contains:

[image]

I have these files as PHP files aswell

1-:Get_Auto1.php

```
<?php
// Database Connection
include("configPDO.php");
// Query to get the usable suggestions
    $likeString = '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%';
// We Will prepare SQL Query
    $STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Barangay FROM Barangays WHERE Barangay LIKE :likeString");
// bind parameters, Named parameters always start with colon(:)
    $STM->bindParam(':likeString', $likeString);
// For Executing prepared statement we will use below function
    $STM->execute();
// we will fetch records like this and use foreach loop to show multiple Results
    $STMrecords = $STM->fetchAll();
// Deifne array for category.
    $Category_array = array();
// Use for each loop to push all results in category array.
foreach($STMrecords as $row)
{
// Store all values in $result variable.
$result = $row[0];
// push all values in category array using array_push function which treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array.
array_push($Category_array, $result);   
}
// encode it using json_encode which returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.      
$json = json_encode($Category_array);
// echo it for getting it using Ajax function explained above.
echo $json;          
?>
```

2- configPDO.php

```
 <?php
// mysql hostname
$hostname = 'fdb3.xxxxxxx.net';
// mysql username
$username = '15740xx_xxxxxx';
// mysql password
$password = 'xxxxxxx';
// Database Connection using PDO with Try Catch Statements
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=1xxxxx_xxxxxx", $username, $password);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where is the relevant jQuery code?

Comment: your have error in your Get_Categories.php : login or password incorrect  
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '1574003_iomdata'@'83.125.22.183' (using password: YES)' in /srv/disk13/1574003/www/iomhumanitarian.atwebpages.com/Get_Categories.php:9Stack trace:#0 /srv/disk13/1574003/www/iomhumanitarian.atwebpages.com/Get_Categories.php(9): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=fdb3...', '1574003_iomdata', 'password')#1 {main} thrown in /srv/disk13/1574003/www/iomhumanitarian.atwebpages.com/Get_Categories.php on line 9

Comment: Lamari and FLF thanks for you comments I fixed the password but still not working! can you please let me know why? can you please let me know where i can see the error message?

Comment: CAn someone please help me on this?